# JQuery how to do conditional resize like css3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, orientation

Right now my site has items shown in a two column using isotope. The problem is since my site is responsive when you change the size of the page the posts will start to overlap. Right now im using a orientation change listener but my function is being called for every pixel thus causing lots of CPU load for no reason at all. Now what I'm trying to do is have it only run the code when a certain condition is met like in css3. For example if the page turns to less then 600px then run function X but it only needs to run once the size is less then that, so it won't run if it goes below 550px or 350px. This is how my code looks like at the moment. ReloadPosts just tells isotope to refresh

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    reloadPosts();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
     $(window).resize(function(){
        setTimeout(doResizing,200);

    });


    function doResizing() {
        if ( $(window).width() > 601 ) { /* do stuff */ }
        if ( $(window).width() < 600 ) { /* do stuff */  }


    };

    doResizing();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [smartresize plugin](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize) that is [included with isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html). Behind the scenes, it uses a debouncing technique so that the resize method doesn't get overwhelmed.

```
var $container = $('#container')

// when you setup isotope, disable normal resizing
$container.isotope({
    // options...
    resizable: false
});

$(window).smartresize(function(){
    // code to handle resizing (i.e. reloadPosts())
});
```